# How to disable KDE Wallet?

Tags: kde5, kwallet

I'm using Ubuntu Maverick (Gnome), a month ago I updated like usual whenever Update Manager informed me of new updates. The thing that happened is that a program called `kdewallet`  got installed on my machine, and every time I try to do something that requires password like `svn`, it pops up and starts getting really annoying. How can I get rid of it? It's not even in the Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: You tagged it "kde", are you using Gnome or KDE? (just to be sure, kde could be a dependency of an other program)

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu uses Gnome and Kubuntu uses KDE. Is that right? and I don't really know why a program called kde-something is running on my computer!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

KDE Wallet is a core part of KDE, it's in the package `kdebase-runtime`.

To disable it run `kcmshell4 kwalletconfig` and continue at step 3 or start from the beginning:

1. Start *System setings*
2. Open *Account Details*
3. Go to the "KDE Wallet" tab
4. Uncheck *Enable the KDE Wallet subsystem*
5. Click `Apply` to apply the changes and close the settings window.

To get a list of the programs that depends on the `kdebase-runtime` package, run:

```
 apt-cache --no-enhances --no-suggests --no-recommends --installed rdepends kdebase-runtime
```

On Ubuntu, the output shows just "kdebase-runtime [newline] Reverse Depends:". On Kubuntu, a whole list follows.

Comment: I can't find this `System settings` you're talking about, I'm using Ubuntu, don't know if it's the case in Kubuntu!

Comment: @David Weng: try running the `kcmshell4 kwalletconfig` command directly. Could you paste the output of `apt-cache --no-enhances --no-suggests --no-recommends --installed rdepends kdebase-runtime` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add that link in a comment?

Comment: This works for some applications but not chrome. I think because there are multiple kwallets floating around. See https://superuser.com/questions/994551/disable-kwallet-popups-from-chrome

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in (K)Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: In Plasma `kcmshell5 kwalletconfig5` worked for me.

Comment: As of today, right command is `kcmshell5 kcm_kwallet5`

Answer (score 16):

I got rid of the "KDE Wallet System" dialog (whenever I started Chrome) as follows:

1. Edit `~/.config/kwalletrc` (see note below), and add

   ```
   [Wallet]
   Enabled=false
   ```
2. Kill the kdewallet daemon:
   `pkill kdewallet5` (or `killall kdewallet5`)

I found this option when I looked through the source code ([on kde.org](https://projects.kde.org/projects/frameworks/kwallet/repository/revisions/a713c1246373b4789db64ebbf1d68df270c21697/entry/src/runtime/kwalletd/kwalletd.cpp#L1495) or at [the Github mirror](https://github.com/KDE/kde-runtime/blob/96063a2b63842a80ca58a876b73d5a1b2bdd53bc/kwalletd/kwalletd.cpp#L1444-L1448)).

If putting `kwalletrc` in `~/.config` does not work, then your system probably uses a different directory for storing configuration files. The config file is created in a directory identified by `QStandardPaths::GenericConfigLocation`, so I used `qtpaths` to look up the path (`~/.config` = `/home/rob/.config` in my case):

```
$ qtpaths --paths GenericConfigLocation
/home/rob/.config:/etc/xdg
```

Note: if you don't want to completely disable kwallet, but only for Chrome, you can use the `--password-store=basic` flag as I explained at [Disable kwallet popups from chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/994551/disable-kwallet-popups-from-chrome/995367#995367). If you start Chrome via a wrapper script or shortcut, I recommend using `--password-store=basic` in case you need kwallet for something else. I disabled kwalletd instead of using this flag because I develop Chrome, and it's inconvenient to add this flag all the time when I run `./chrome`.

<sub>(Tested on ArchLinux, but it should also work on Ubuntu. Use `sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools` if you want to use `qtpaths` to find the configuration directory).</sub>

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 10):

I executed:

1. Start *System settings*.
2. Go to the *Advanced* tab.
3. Press *KDE Wallet* icon.
4. Uncheck *Enable the KDE Wallet subsystem*.

OS: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

---

In Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty), step (2) is now "Go to *Account Details*"

Answer (score 3):

I use **Ubuntu 16.04.LTS** and found the 'kdwalletrc' file in this path

```
~/.kde/share/config/kdwalletrc
```

Switch the option 'Enable' from 'true' to 'false' to disable kdeWallet

```
[Wallet]
Close When Idle=false
Enabled=false
```

Comment: When I look on my 16.04 system, I see ~/.kde/share/ but there is no config directory. I still have the KDE wallet system prompting me every time I reboot.

Answer (score 0):

## Disable password required notification Kwallet

#### RESUME

KDE menu => system preferences => notifications => wallet (dropdown) => password required option => show popup (uncheck) => reboot.

#### DESCRIPTION

I'm spanish and maybe the options could have another translation.

I use **KDE Plasma 5.12**. Open the KDE menu and search **"system preferences"** and click on it. Now search for **"notifications"**. At top right of the window you could see a dropdown, in my case, I had already choosen **"accesibility"** option, then change it and choose **"wallet"**. The last step, click on **"password required"** option and **uncheck show pop up** or something similar (at bottom). Save and reboot, done :-).

Hope it helps and you can disable this annoying notifications.