# Uninstall KDE Wallet from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, kde, kwallet

I'm trying to uninstall or disable KDE Wallet. I can't find it in the Ubuntu Software Centre and it doesn't seem to be listed when I do: `dpkg -l`

I found some instructions how to remove it in 10.10 here: https://askubuntu.com/a/47218/101048

However, there is no "Account Details" section in "System Settings" in my version of Ubuntu, and when I run "kcmshell4 kwalletconfig", I get the following error:

```
Could not find module 'kwalletconfig'. See kcmshell4 --list for the full list of modules.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to disable it by setting "Enabled=false" in the file `~/.kde/share/config/kwalletrc` and then restarting (or `pkill -SIGHUP kwalletd`).