# How to fully disable kde wallet?

Tags: ssh, kde, kwallet

I'm on kubuntu 15.04. I'd like to use ksshaskpass, but whenever I run it, I get requestor to create kdewallet.

I did disable kdewallet, as shown in [How to disable KDE Wallet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47216/how-to-disable-kde-wallet) , any my config files seem to reflect it:

```
=$ grep -i enabled .kde/share/config/kwalletrc 
Enabled=false
```

But the requestor is still there (even after reboot).

Currently I'm using text-mode password requestor, so that it doesn't ask for kde wallet creation, but I think that there has to be a way to make it understand that I don't want it to remember password and I definitely don't want to use wallet.

Comment: Same problem here. Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594260/how-to-disable-kwallet-in-kde-plasma-5

Which version of Plasma are you using? I can't disable KWallet on Plasma 5.3.